# Separating fields based on string match and semicolon

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some data:

```
> dput(data)
structure(list(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID = c("DIS-1101-1001-E1", "DIS-1101-1002-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1003-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E2", "DIS-1101-1005-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1006-E1", "DIS-1101-1007-E1", "DIS-1101-1008-E1", "DIS-1101-1009-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1010-E1", "DIS-1101-1011-E1", "DIS-1101-1012-E1", "DIS-1101-1013-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1014-E1", "DIS-1101-1015-E1", "DIS-1101-1016-E1", "DIS-1101-1017-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1018-E1", "DIS-1101-1019-E1"), `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN` = c("BASELINE=123.00;FIRST=117.00", 
"FIRST=92.00", "FIRST=111.00", "BASELINE=125.00;FIRST=113.00", 
"FIRST=124.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=77.00", "FIRST=132.00", 
"FIRST=123.00", "BASELINE=119.00;FIRST=93.00", "BASELINE=163.00;FIRST=141.00", 
"FIRST=137.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=137.00", "FIRST=127.00", 
"BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=101.00;SECOND=105.00", "FIRST=120.00", "FIRST=145.00"
)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to split the data into baseline, first, second, and third for each ID:

```
haem_id_sep <- tidyr::separate(data.frame(text = data$`TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`), text, into = c("haemoglobin_baseline", "haemoglobin_first", "haemoglobin_second", "haemoglobin_third"), sep = ";", fill = "right", extra = "drop")
```

I can split by semi-colon into 4 categories `haemoglobin_baseline`, `haemoglobin_first`, `haemoglobin_second`, `haemoglobin_third`, however the issue is have is that some entries are all NULL which need to be NA across all columns, and some do not have a baseline reading, so the columns are off (i.e. first readings are appearing in the baseline column). Essentially I need to print to the baseline column if there is a baseline value, print to the first column if there is a first value and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can take a different approach -

- Use `separate_rows` to split data in different rows on `;`.
- Use `separate` to divide the text in two columns
- Drop the `'NULL'` value rows.
- Get the data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  rename(text = `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`) %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = ';') %>%
  separate(text, c('text', 'value'), sep = '=') %>%
  filter(!(text == 'NULL' | value == 'NULL')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = text, values_from = value)

#  UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID BASELINE FIRST  SECOND
#   <chr>             <chr>    <chr>  <chr> 
# 1 DIS-1101-1001-E1  123.00   117.00 NA    
# 2 DIS-1101-1002-E1  NA       92.00  NA    
# 3 DIS-1101-1003-E1  NA       111.00 NA    
# 4 DIS-1101-1004-E1  125.00   113.00 NA    
# 5 DIS-1101-1004-E2  NA       124.00 NA    
# 6 DIS-1101-1007-E1  NA       77.00  NA    
# 7 DIS-1101-1008-E1  NA       132.00 NA    
# 8 DIS-1101-1009-E1  NA       123.00 NA    
# 9 DIS-1101-1010-E1  119.00   93.00  NA    
#10 DIS-1101-1011-E1  163.00   141.00 NA    
#11 DIS-1101-1012-E1  NA       137.00 NA    
#12 DIS-1101-1015-E1  NA       137.00 NA    
#13 DIS-1101-1016-E1  NA       127.00 NA    
#14 DIS-1101-1017-E1  NA       101.00 105.00
#15 DIS-1101-1018-E1  NA       120.00 NA    
#16 DIS-1101-1019-E1  NA       145.00 NA
```

Answer (score 2):

We could do this in `base R` with `read.dcf`

```
# // replace the `=` with `:` and `;` with `\n` using `chartr` and `paste`
# // into a single string
tmp <- paste(chartr("=;", ":\n", data$`TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`), 
          collapse = "\n\n")
# // read with `read.dcf` and `cbind` to the original dataset
out <- cbind(data["UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID"], 
        read.dcf(textConnection(tmp))[,-3])
out[out == "NULL"] <- NA
out <- type.convert(out, as.is = TRUE)
out <- subset(out, !!rowSums(!is.na(out[-1])))
```

-output

```
   UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID BASELINE FIRST SECOND
1   DIS-1101-1001-E1      123   117     NA
2   DIS-1101-1002-E1       NA    92     NA
3   DIS-1101-1003-E1       NA   111     NA
4   DIS-1101-1004-E1      125   113     NA
5   DIS-1101-1004-E2       NA   124     NA
8   DIS-1101-1007-E1       NA    77     NA
9   DIS-1101-1008-E1       NA   132     NA
10  DIS-1101-1009-E1       NA   123     NA
11  DIS-1101-1010-E1      119    93     NA
12  DIS-1101-1011-E1      163   141     NA
13  DIS-1101-1012-E1       NA   137     NA
16  DIS-1101-1015-E1       NA   137     NA
17  DIS-1101-1016-E1       NA   127     NA
18  DIS-1101-1017-E1       NA   101    105
19  DIS-1101-1018-E1       NA   120     NA
20  DIS-1101-1019-E1       NA   145     NA
```